# need help identifying an outdoor drain

Tags: drain, pvc, french-drain

We just got into a new house that's built into a hill.

Can anyone tell me what these are?

I think the dark drain is part of a french drain, but near that is an open PVC pipe that's pretty much just a nest for mosquitoes right now.

Any idea what the function of the open PVC pipe is or advice to fix it? TIA

[image: french]

[image: mosquitonest]

[image: undercover]

Comment: The first picture is definitely a drain cover. Can you lift up the cover and see what's underneath it?

Comment: The white thing might be a cleanout, which should be capped.  Is there anything in it?

Answer (score 3):

The box is a collection drain box.  It should not be 1/2 filled with dirt.

Dig the dirt out.  You will find 1 or more "ports"  where the water collected in the box should drain out.  Where that terminates is something you will have to apply detective skills to.

The exit drains may be partially filled with dirt as well.  You will have to get out a hose and see how successful you can be in cleaning it out.  Running water into the drain may show you where that water goes.

Good Luck